# RWCString - pass by value or const reference

Tags: c++, performance, string

I work on a project that uses extensively RWCStrings. They are refcount-ed and thread safe so I've always wondered if it's better to pass them to functions by value and take advantage of the ref-counting, or by const reference and bypass that (assuming the function is read-only).

Which one is better/faster? Any special considerations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Const-reference. Not using it means calling the copy-constructor, which means a function call and some access to the memory. Passing by const-reference means, basically, passing a pointer; thus there is zero overhead.